# How to get rectangular grid co-ordinate with 2 geo points

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

Given two geo points say

```
(27.172079,78.047229) and (26.171239,75.037778)
```

Is it possible to get other two geo co-ordinate so as to form rectangular polygon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible.

lat1,lon1 
lat1,lon2
lat2,lon2
lat2,lon1

With googlemap api v2 you can easily get northeast and southwest coordinates.

```
llBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
point = new LatLng(lat,lon);
llBuilder.include(point);
point = new LatLng(lat2, lon2);
llBuilder.include(point);
calcBounds = llBuilder.build();
calcBounds.northeast.

log.d( ...
calcBounds.northeast.latitude,calcBounds.northeast.longitude
calcBounds.northeast.latitude,calcBounds.southwest.longitude
calcBounds.southwest.latitude, calBounds.southwest.longitude
calcBounds.southwest.Latitude, calcBounds.northeast.longitude
...
);
```

Comment: Can I get some thing similar in java application ? my requirement is to create a rectangular area based on start and end location and   ensure vehicle is not deviated out of that area.

Comment: IDK what libs are available for java application but the four corners are lat1,lon1 lat1,lon2 lat2,lon2 lat2,lon1 where lat1 is 27.172079 lon1 is 78.047229 lat 2 is 26.171239 lon2 is 75.037778